# Possible to change these 2 SQL queries into 1?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to change these 2 queries into 1?

Query #1:

```sql
UPDATE  `pvdownloader`.`posts`
SET  `exists` =  'y'
WHERE source = ANY (SELECT source FROM dbdownloader.posts)
  AND `mangacount` = 0
  AND NOT `exists` = 'm'
```

Query #2:

```sql
UPDATE `pvdownloader`.`posts`
SET  `exists` =  'n'
WHERE `exists` = 'u'
  AND `mangacount` = 0
```

I'm assuming it would be possible to make something like this with IF/ELSE but I can't figure out how to use it at all :<

Comment: Logic says `AND NOT mangacount !=0` is the same as `AND mangacount = 0` :)

Comment: you can try [mysql case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statements.

Comment: Oh, never thought about that xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
update
  pvdownloader.posts
set
  exists =
    case
      when source = any(select source from dbdownloader.posts) and mangacount = 0 and exists != 'm' then 'y'
      when exists = 'u' and mangacount = 0 then 'n'
    end
where 
  (source = any(select source from dbdownloader.posts) and mangacount = 0 and exists != 'm')
  or
  (exists = 'u' and mangacount = 0)
;
```

As @MostyMostacho suggested, I took the liberty of changing your logic to not have a double-negative.

Comment: Works perfect, isn't much a speed improvement over using two queries as I had hoped though :<

Comment: Yeah there's no way I would call that operation fast.  It has to do two inner-selects if you use the where clause, which you should.  It also has to run that case comparison on every row in the table.  If MySQL supported with clauses it would be a bit faster, but, sadly, it doesn't.